# Unable to click on login button of paytm. It will highlight but will not click. Below is my code

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am unable to click on login button of paytm. It will highlight but will not click.

The code works perfectly in Firefox. It's not able to click the link in Chrome browser. It's not showing any error or exception, it's just not able to click.

Below is my code:

```
driver.get("https://paytm.com/");
WebElement LoginLink= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Log In/Sign Up')]"));
Highlight.highLightElement(driver, LoginLink);
LoginLink.click();
```

Comment: what is the error/exception. what do you mean by not clicking. is it on all browser or some specific browser? which version of firefox or chrome driver?

Comment: Not working in Chrome browser, firefox it is working. not clicking means not clicking on Login Button. Below is my code

WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("https://paytm.com/");
WebElement LoginLink= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Log In/Sign Up')]"));
 Highlight.highLightElement(driver, LoginLink);
 LoginLink.click();

Answer (score 1):

```
public class LoginPage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        String url="https://paytm.com/";
        driver.get(url);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement Login=(WebElement) driver.findElement(By.className("_3ac-"));
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", Login);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow ! Please, don't just put code in your answer, give some context, some explanations so that the people understand what the code actually does.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

You can use the following code block to click on **`Log In/Sign Up`** button on `https://paytm.com/` through `Google Chrome 59.0`:

> Note: As a quick fix to your issue I have induced `Thread.sleep(5000);` which should be replaced by `ExplicitWait` i.e `WebDriverWait`

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class Q45102095_PAYTM 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); 
        WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://paytm.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement login_button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='app']//div[normalize-space(text()) = 'Log In/Sign Up']"));
        login_button.click();
    }
}
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Check my updated Answer and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.get("https://paytm.com/");

Thread.sleep(2000);

JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

WebElement Login_Btn= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Log In/Sign Up')]"));

je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",Login_Btn);

Login_Btn.click();

Comment: Great, it's working. Thank you so much. Can you please explain this code how it is working by using this function and class

Comment: After login to paytm we need to scroll to that element(login button), then only it can find the element and we can perform the action.